# Where ifconfig informations are stored?

Tags: raspbian, networking, jessie-lite

Where are saved the information given by ifconfig command on raspbian?

I need to read these informations from a file.

Is there any file where (as an example) the mac address of an interface is stored?

Comment: Not specific to the Raspberry Pi.  Why don't you just parse the output of the ifconfig command and extract the MAC?

Comment: Note that `ifconfig` has been considered obsolete for years on linux (see `man ifconfig`) and exists only for backward compatibility.

Comment: @joan because i need to use a lot of scripts that involve the Mac addresses, I think is not handy parsing the output of ifconfig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raspbian is a Linux based operating system and in Linux most information like the information provided by the `ifconfig` command is available in a special file.  From [this Superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/544653/easy-way-to-get-mac-address-of-network-card#544661) the MAC address is available by reading `/sys/class/net/$iFACE/address` where `$iFACE` is a shell variable that contains the interface name desired.  Or just by explicitly reading file `/sys/class/net/eth0/addresss` for interface `eth0`.

```
raspberrypi ~ $ cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address
b8:27:eb:a3:f9:94
```

Comment: Worth noting that these are not files in a conventional sense of information serialized on disk somewhere (or serialized and stored at all).   They do not exist when the system is not running.  They are nodes created (mostly at boot) and maintained by the kernel; read requests on them are direct requests for information from the kernel, and write requests send information to the kernel.   This goes back to the Unix ["everything is a file"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file) design principle.